# Partitioning data in a multi-tenant format efficiently.

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm working on a database that will be storing products from multiple accounts. 
The number of products for a given account could vary significantly and I want to be able to easily query products for a specific account.

At the moment I have a table similar to this.

```
CREATE TABLE key.products (
    product_id UUID,
    account_id UUID,
    sku TEXT,
    other_details....,
    PRIMARY KEY (account_id, product_id, sku)
);
```

This table will let me use queries like this quite easily.

```
SELECT product_id,sku,other_details FROM key.products WHERE account_id=@@@@;
```

But if I get a handful of accounts that have significantly more products than other accounts it would offset the partitions in Cassandra; and I would no longer have a good and equal distribution of data among my nodes. The data would still be relatively easy to query by account_id but is this okay? At what point will I be shooting myself in the foot for not partitioning with something else? 
And how can I change my approach to still query products in an account efficiently and minimize data skew?

Would partitioning by product_id instead and have an alternate table to query by account be more efficient? Something like.

```
CREATE TABLE key.products (
    product_id UUID,
    sku TEXT,
    other_details....,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id, sku)
);

CREATE TABLE key.products_by_account (
    account_id UUID,
    product_id UUID,
    PRIMARY KEY (account_id, product_id)
);
```

The data would still skew in the products_by_account table but the size of the data would be much smaller since it does not contain all the data in the main products table. Is this better?

Comment: I would recommend to first list all your queries...

Comment: The big one for the primary products table will be the one above, except it will be paged using token(product_id) in the UI. Other than that there will only be one off queries that are rarely executed which will "allow filtering" but are executed so infrequently that it will not be worth optimizing for them.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why Cassandra?

Comment: This is going to be for a barcode scanning application that's in the cloud. We want to be able to scale up or down as needed and we have not had good luck with distributed relational databases. We've been able to achieve the low latency and performance we need using Cassandra, but we want to make sure we aren't trying to force it to do something it's not supposed to. And we may still switch databases; Cassandra has just been the most performant database we've tested in development so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data modeling in Cassandra happens around queries - you need to think how queries will look like...

In your case, the good distribution could be with composite partition key, like `(account_id, product_id)`.

Another approach, is to add some kind of bucketing to "big" accounts - for example, split account's data into N buckets, and use key like `(account_id, X)`, where X is between 0 & N.  In this case, if you ever need to have need to fetch all products for given account, you can issue N queries in parallel to fetch everything. Instead of number, you can use product's categories, or something like, that has fixed & known set of values.

Comment: So maybe set a threshold for products in buckets. Once an account gets to say 5000 products it starts a new bucket and have that be part of the partition key?

Comment: Something like, but you need to know how many buckets will be for customer

Comment: I think I'm going to do a combination of both. I think I will have the account id in two tables and have the products_by_account table for blanket queries. But I will add a bucket_id column to that one to split it up a bit more. And then I will make the partition key in the products table the product_id instead.

For queries looking for an exact product_id this will be fast. And for when they are looking at products in the account it will need to do 2 queries if they want to see all the info but that might not be so bad.